# Can connect to some routers but not others 14.04

Tags: 14.04, networking, internet

New Acer Aspire laptop, Ubuntu 14.04. Works great on wifi or wired connection, with one exception: I can't connect to my TP-Link TL-WR702N router, neither wired nor wirelessly.  Ubuntu sees the wireless AP and will let me enter the password, but will just churn a while and then not connect. If I plug the laptop into the Ethernet port, it does basically the same thing, just churns a while (meaning that the little wifi icon throbs and then goes to outline).  The router works fine for other computers, my tablet, phone, etc. The laptop works fine with other routers.  What could be the difference?

Comment: Reboot the router and see what happens.

Comment: Of course the router has been rebooted many times.  I've been working on this problem for days.

Comment: Please provide system log from during your attempts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar issues with some routers on my end the only way I was able to connect was by changing the mac address even though there was not any filter by mac set up on the router. I used `macchanger`, to install simply open a terminal and type:

```
sudo apt-get install macchanger
```

And to assign a new one simply run:

```
sudo macchanger -a [interface you want to change (in my case wlan0)]
```

Make sure the interface is down at the moment you assign the new mac address you can do so by simple unchecking the options enable networking/wifi from the network manager menu.

Comment: Wow, I would have bet money that that would not fix it, but it did.  Perhaps a bug in the router firmware?  One other weird thing is that on the wireless side, macchanger would change the MAC address, but it would change back as soon as I tried to connect the wifi.  Changing it manually with ifconfig did the trick, though.  Awesome!

Comment: In regards why this happens I have no idea however with macchanger what happens is that it will go back to its default once the interface goes down so if you have the option of automatically connect to this network what it does is that changes the address if you simply turn the wireless on it will connect on the network using the fake mac however if you click on the network while turning on the wifi it will change to its default because the interface goes down twice. it has an option to create a mac everytime interface goes down which is what I use so I dont have that problem