# Error message *-network UNCLAIMED showing after install wifi driver with Windows Wireless Drivers

Tags: 14.04, networking, drivers, ralink

I use a RT3290 Wireless 802.11n 1T/1R PCIe wifi card. This card does not has a proper driver for ubuntu, I tried several post but I had no luck. Now I've tried to install windows driver for the card using Windows Wireless Drivers, and I have attached the picture.

[image]

Here the driver installed properly. But after installation the driver is not recognized by the Ubuntu. Here is the output of `sudo lshw -C network`

```
rashed@rashed-HP-250-G3-Notebook-PC:~$ sudo lshw -C network[sudo] password for rashed: 
  *-network               
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL8101E/RTL8102E PCI Express Fast Ethernet controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:08:00.0
       logical name: eth0
       version: 07
       serial: d0:bf:9c:12:20:73
       size: 100Mbit/s
       capacity: 100Mbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=2.3LK-NAPI duplex=full firmware=rtl8106e-1_0.0.1 06/29/12 ip=192.168.0.103 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=MII speed=100Mbit/s
       resources: irq:41 ioport:4000(size=256) memory:b5600000-b5600fff memory:b5400000-b5403fff
  *-network UNCLAIMED
       description: Network controller
       product: RT3290 Wireless 802.11n 1T/1R PCIe
       vendor: Ralink corp.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:0a:00.0
       version: 00
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: memory:b5510000-b551ffff
```

Output of `iwconfig` is

```
eth0      no wireless extensions.

lo        no wireless extensions.
```

And the out put of `sudo modprobe ndiswrapper` and then `dmesg | grep ndis`
is

```
rashed@rashed-HP-250-G3-Notebook-PC:~$ sudo modprobe ndiswrapper
[sudo] password for rashed: 
rashed@rashed-HP-250-G3-Notebook-PC:~$ dmesg | grep ndis
[   13.656731] ndiswrapper: module verification failed: signature and/or  required key missing - tainting kernel
[   13.657662] ndiswrapper version 1.59 loaded (smp=yes, preempt=no)
[   15.471685] ndiswrapper (import:232): unknown symbol: ntoskrnl.exe:'ExEventObjectType'
[   15.471693] ndiswrapper (import:232): unknown symbol: ntoskrnl.exe:'__chkstk'
[   15.471788] ndiswrapper (load_sys_files:200): couldn't prepare driver 'rt2860'
[   15.472274] ndiswrapper (load_wrap_driver:103): couldn't load driver rt2860; check system log for messages from 'loadndisdriver'
[   15.473400] usbcore: registered new interface driver ndiswrapper
```

As you can see, for the wireless card, the the error message -network UNCLAIMED is there. Now if any one has a solution for this I would really appreciate to share it with me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please run: `sudo modprobe ndiswrapper` and then run: `dmesg | grep ndis` Edit your question to add the result.

Comment: Hello @chili555 I have update the post with the result, Please take a look....

Comment: `unknown symbol` generally suggests you have the wrong driver files. ndiswrapper needs Windows XP (not 7 nor Vista, etc.) .inf and .sys files appropriate to your architecture; either 32- or 64-bit. Is that what you have?

Comment: Hey the driver Id Of my wifi card is PCI\VEN_1814&DEV_3290&SUBSYS_18EC103C&REV_00 and the name is Ralink RT3290 802.11bgn Wi-Fi Adapter. I have driver for windows vista and windows 7 and windows 8 but not for windows xp .. :(

Comment: In most recent Ubuntu versions, this device is driven by the native driver `rt2800pci`. Is this not working for you?

Comment: Hey I found a driver for windows xp the link is http://devid.info/p467380/Ralink+RT3290+802.11bgn+Wi-Fi+Adapter . And I have update the post with recent result from the terminal .... have a look please.

Comment: Please join me in chat: http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/31589/discussion-between-rashed-azad-and-chili555

Comment: Hi - your question was fixed by chili555 in chat? maybe you should post your own answer with the solution :)

Comment: @chili555 could you post an answer to this question?

Comment: @Zanna - I don't know how or why it occurred,  but the answer is here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/694167/wifi-get-disconnected-automatically

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Wifi get disconnected automatically](http://askubuntu.com/questions/694167/wifi-get-disconnected-automatically)

Answer (score 0):

Run the following command:

```
sudo modprobe ndiswrapper
```

If this show you  `"Required key not available"`,then follow this [link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/762254/why-do-i-get-required-key-not-available-when-install-3rd-party-kernel-modules).
I don't have much knowledge of Ubuntu but this fixed my problem.