# Bizzare scenario in Ubuntu 17.10

Tags: networking, 17.10

I usually work with Ubuntu 17.10, Intel i5, 8GB (laptop A) and connected to a home wifi network. Sometimes unusually this laptop A won't connect to the wifi, so I would be offline. I used to restart multiple times and try again and again connecting to the home wifi network, but I wouldn't be able to connect.

Once I got fed up and took another laptop B (Ubuntu 17.10, Intel i3, 2GB) and just started the machine and logged into the wifi network. Then laptop A would automatically connect. I didn't think this was a solution but a weird event, but whenever I had the issue I just did this and my laptop A got connected to wifi. What could be the reason for this? Does anyone have any idea?

Comment: Sounds like a router issue to me -- and if so, it'd be off topic on this SE.

Comment: I suggest that you try the router steps here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/694167/wifi-gets-disconnected-automatically/699209#699209 The *rt2800* step probably doesn't apply to you.